# IOS application opening files in Keynote, generating dupes

Tags: ios

So I have the following working in my app and when called it copies the resource file to Keynote and opens it just fine:

```
documentController =  [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
documentController.delegate = self;
[documentController retain];
[documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
[documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(500,-200 , 200, 200) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

The problem is that everytime the code's triggered, it copies the file to Keynote again, essentially creating a duplicate.

Any way to get around creating the dupe?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?